# Sharing data between apple watch and iPhone using Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, watchkit, apple-watch

I've made the following DataAccess.swift file to share Core Data between Apple Watch and iPhone app inside a framework. The app in the phone runs perfectly while it shows an error when the apple watch runs.

```
public  lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {

    let proxyBundle = NSBundle(identifier: "group.com.qburst.toDoListAppGroup")
    **let modelURL = proxyBundle?.URLForResource("DateSaver", withExtension: "momd")!**

    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL!)!
    }()
```

For the above code, I get an error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) "  for the marked line in the code.

I've followed this tutorial from [GitHub](https://github.com/aalittle/CoreDataWatchKit)

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with code or the reason why the Watch app fails?

Comment: From the error, `proxyBundle` seems to be nil.

Comment: This comment is just a suggestion to use MMWormhole to easily share data between host app and the watch. https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you misunderstood what a bundle identifier is, bundle identifier is not a way to load a bundle from disc, it's a way to identify bundles after it has been loaded.

In the demo code on Github, the `NSManagedObjectModel` is retrieved by this way:

```
public lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("CoreDataWatch", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
        }()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you turned on App Groups in both targets, under xcode's Build Capabilities tab.